# iPhone TabBarController Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uitabbarcontroller, transition

I'm building an iPhone app that seems to have a rather unorthodox navigation layout. The entire thing is built on top of a UITabBarController, but I've modified the bounds of the first view in order to make the tab bar "disappear." Instead of using the tab bar, in order to navigate away from the first page, the user clicks an info button that I have placed in the bottom right of the screen. When that button is clicked, I have it set to run this code:

```
self.tabBarController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view.window cache:YES];
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

That code has the bottom right corner of the view curl up revealing a UINavigationController's view embedded in the second tab of the UITabBarController and makes the tab bar reappear. I am very, very pleased with the animation that brings me from the initial view to the UINavigationController. What I can't seem to figure out, however, is how to do the opposite animation going backwards when I hit the tab that corresponds to the original view. So far I've played around with a few different ways of implementing this code:

```
self.tabBarController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 575);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view.window cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

in the `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` methods, but then the animation runs by animating the view over an image of itself (so it curls back down, but as it's curling you can see that the view beneath it is the same view). I am specifically looking for a way to achieve the same thing but have the view beneath be whatever view from the UITabBarController that I just came from.

TLDR; I want to implement a curl up, curl down animation transition to and from a view that is part of a UITabBarController, but needs to look like it isn't.